# Langevin Paramagnetism for dipoles rotating in 2D

Tags: statistical-mechanics

The energy for dipoles in a magnetic field can be described by $$H = - \mathbf{m} \cdot \mathbf{B}.$$ What I did for an exercise was integrate the partition function for the case where I allow rotation in three dimensions (reducing it to the integral $Z_1 = \int_0^{2 \pi} d \varphi \int_0^{\pi} d \theta \sin(\theta) e^{\beta m B \cos(\theta)}$ and taking the $N$-th power) but I do not know how to set up the integral only allowing 2D rotations. If I take polar coordinates, my length element doesn't contain $\sin(\theta)$ anymore so the integral is hard to solve. Any ideas how to set up the integral for the partition function for the 2D case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) (see the particular case for integer $n$ near the bottom of the page and note that setting $n=0$ essentially yields the integral you want).

Comment: Alright thank you!